# how do i get this values using php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

```
[
 ["STRG008c0",2,0,"orange","***STRG008*#*"], 
 ["STRG009c0",3,0,"orange","***STRG009*#*"], 
 ["STRG001c0",2,0,"green","***STRG001*#*"], 
 ["STRG003c0",3,0,"green","***STRG003*#*"], 
 ["STRG002c0",4,0,"green","***STRG002*#*"]
]
```

How do I get the below in a loop in PHP?

```
***STRG008*#*
***STRG009*#*
***STRG001*#*
***STRG003*#*
***STRG002*#*
```

Comment: *STRG008# 
*STRG009#
 *STRG001#
 *STRG003# 
*STRG002#

Comment: What did you try as a loop syntax?

Comment: Can you please make it more clear

Comment: Basic `foreach()` and retrieving `key=>value` from an array. But we're not gonna write the code for you. Try it yourself, and if you get stuck, ask here.

Comment: Just loop and use `end()` for your individual subarray.

Comment: @RasikaBandaranayaka Any update?

Comment: <?php $query_aailable_item= "SELECT proposal_item_id,items FROM rack_p_i_elements WHERE rack_proposals_id='".@$selectedProposal."'";
   $res_aailable_item= mysql_query($query_aailable_item);
 $res_aailable_item = mysql_query($query_aailable_item);

 $count=1;
 
  while(@$row_aailable_item=mysql_fetch_array($res_aailable_item)){
         
@$nn.=substr(trim($row_aailable_item['items']), 1, -1).',';
}
$fullAry="[".substr(trim($nn),0, -1)."]";
echo "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".$fullAry;

Comment: [link]https://ibb.co/GprjGfX

this is my loop which is generating array text

Comment: DB is like this https://ibb.co/7gds9M7

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the last column values as a string.

**Method 1:**

Collect all last values of each subarray in a new variable, say `$result` and `implode()` them later.

```
<?php

$array = [
     ["STRG008c0",2,0,"orange","***STRG008*#*"], 
     ["STRG009c0",3,0,"orange","***STRG009*#*"], 
     ["STRG001c0",2,0,"green","***STRG001*#*"], 
     ["STRG003c0",3,0,"green","***STRG003*#*"], 
     ["STRG002c0",4,0,"green","***STRG002*#*"]
    ];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    $result[] = end($subarray);
} 

$result = implode(",",$result);

echo $result;
```

**Method 2:**

You can use `array_column()` to filter only last column values and `implode()` them later. This would be a one-liner.

```
<?php

$array = [
     ["STRG008c0",2,0,"orange","***STRG008*#*"], 
     ["STRG009c0",3,0,"orange","***STRG009*#*"], 
     ["STRG001c0",2,0,"green","***STRG001*#*"], 
     ["STRG003c0",3,0,"green","***STRG003*#*"], 
     ["STRG002c0",4,0,"green","***STRG002*#*"]
    ];


$result = implode(",", array_column($array,4));
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through an array of arrays

```
$a = [
["STRG008c0",2,0,"orange","***STRG008*#*"], 
["STRG009c0",3,0,"orange","***STRG009*#*"], 
["STRG001c0",2,0,"green","***STRG001*#*"], 
["STRG003c0",3,0,"green","***STRG003*#*"], 
["STRG002c0",4,0,"green","***STRG002*#*"]
];

$keys = array_keys($a);
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    
    foreach($a[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 4) 
          echo $value . "\n";
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you for help me.actually its genarate from loop,so may be that is the reson its not work ..
something like this

$fullAry="[".substr(trim($nn),0, -1)."]";
//echo "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".$fullAry;
$firstArray=array($fullAry);


$keys = array_keys($firstArray);
for(@$i = 0; $i < count(@$a); @$i++) {
    
    foreach($a[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 4) 
          echo "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx". $value . "\n";
    }
    ;
}

  ?>

Comment: my generated text is like this
["STRG008c0",2,0,"orange","***STRG008*#*"],["STRG009c0",3,0,"orange","***STRG009*#*"],["STRG001c0",2,0,"green","***STRG001*#*"],["STRG003c0",3,0,"green","***STRG003*#*"],["STRG002c0",4,0,"green","***STRG002*#*"]

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the inner array:

```
$array = [
     ["STRG008c0",2,0,"orange","***STRG008*#*"], 
     ["STRG009c0",3,0,"orange","***STRG009*#*"], 
     ["STRG001c0",2,0,"green","***STRG001*#*"], 
     ["STRG003c0",3,0,"green","***STRG003*#*"], 
     ["STRG002c0",4,0,"green","***STRG002*#*"]
    ];


    foreach ($array as $array_element) {
        echo $array_element[sizeOf($array_element) - 1]."\n";
    }
```

Comment: ["STRG008c0",2,0,"orange","**STRG008*#"],["STRG009c0",3,0,"orange","**STRG009*#"],["STRG001c0",2,0,"green","**STRG001*#"],["STRG003c0",3,0,"green","**STRG003*#"],["STRG002c0",4,0,"green","**STRG002*#"]

Comment: Can you be specific to the problem, which you facing? @RasikaBandaranayaka